# Counting date parts based on the number of months

Tags: excel

I have a column in excel that contains date in the format 01/03/2017. and I want to count the number of occurrence of the months in that date column.

example if I have 5 dates that have the month of one, I want to count that number. here is the code I am trying to use and it doesn't help.

```
=COUNTIF('2017'!$A$2:$A$19,MONTH('2017'!$A$2:$A$19)=1)
```

it just returns zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH('2017'!$A$2:$A$19)=1))
```

If you want to use COUNTIF you will need COUNTIFS() with the date bracketed:

```
=COUNTIFS(2017'!$A$2:$A$19,">=1/1/2017",2017'!$A$2:$A$19,"<2/1/2017")
```